Confusion about Standard Error of Measurement (SEM)
The problem is this: I want to "estimate the error made when attempting to predict the true score from the observed score when I am using an unreliable measurement" (Theory of Mental Tests, Gulliksen, 1950). For example, I might want to evaluate the endurance of an athlete, but result of my test between two sessions for the same subjectcan vary randomly due to biological variability and other factors (subject error, temperature, etc).
Say this test has reliability $R$. This may have been evaluated as an ICC as in this paper, or other methods, this is not relevant here.
Theoretically, the SEM is the standard deviation of a large number of repeated measurements on the same subject. Of course this is not practical to measure so other methods are used.
Many sources online, including some answers on this site, claim that when doing a single test a group of subjects using a with known reliability, the SEM is then calculated as:
$$SEM = \sigma_x*\sqrt{1 - R}$$
Where $\sigma_x$ is the observed group standard deviation and the $ICC$ is the reliability of the test. This is where my confusion starts because I don't understand the justification for using the group SD to estimate the error made in predicting a single individual's true score from the observed score. For example if run a thought experiment where we know that the error of measurement is around 2 test units, but the standard deviation of the group is large, like 30 units, there is no way we will get a good estimation of the error from using the group mean.
My confusion is reinforced by the fact that in Gulliksen's book, cited also by an NCME Instructional Module, another formula is used:
$$SE = \sigma_x \sqrt{R}\sqrt{1-R}$$
and called the standard error of estimate, seemingly the one I should use in my case.
But it's not over. Other sources suggest that the SEM can also be calculated in other ways, like for example:
$$SEM = \frac{\sigma_{diff}}{\sqrt{2}}$$
where $\sigma_{diff}$ is the standard deviation of the difference of the scores observed when conducting the test-retest reliability study, which looks like a completely different quantity. This is more intuitive to me because we don't have the issue ofusing group variance to estiate individual level error, the variance of the difference is used instead.
So which quantity do I actually want to use to achieve my goal, which is estimating the error made when predicting the true score from the observed score (ultimately by placing confidence intervals around an individual's measurement) when the reliability is known? And if the formula involves $\sigma_x$, what is the justification for using group level statistics to estimate individual level error?

I have no idea what this is: $ SE=σ\sqrt R \sqrt(1- R) $ is. but the short answer to your question depends on whether you know the observed standard deviation and the reliability R. If you do, then $ SEM = σ_x \cdot \sqrt(1- R) $ can be used. Otherwise, $ \frac{\sigma_{diff}}{\sqrt(2)} $. They are mathematically equivalent (I am not going to do that math here as I don't have time. But I did check Chat GPT to see if it gives the right calculations and it did for me so you shouldn't have trouble getting that math if you were curious)
P.S. FYI, the $ \frac{\sigma_{diff}}{\sqrt(2)} $ formula is derived from the variance of differences formula $ \text{Var}(X_2 - X_1) = \text{Var}(E_2 - E_1) =\text{Var}(E_1) + \text{Var}(E_2) - 2 \cdot \text{Cov}(E_1,E_2) $ if you assume the errors are independent and thus $ \text{Cov}(E_1,E_2)=0 $ and thus simplifying to the $ {\sigma_{diff}}=\sqrt {2 \cdot Var(E)} $ formula. From there you divide both sides by $ \sqrt 2 $ to get the standard error for the single measurement instead of for the difference (the standard deviation of differences ($\sigma_{diff}$) is $ \sqrt 2 $ times larger than the SEM if that was not clear).
But that is why you would use $ \frac{\sigma_{diff}}{\sqrt(2)} $. you are calculating the standard error of measurement. Though, if you do know the reliability R nad the observed standard deviation $ \sigma_x $, then $ SEM = \sigma_x \cdot \sqrt{1-R} $ can be used in the place of $ \frac{\sigma_{diff}}{\sqrt(2)} $ as they are equivalent.
As for group data, I am not sure what you mean. In both instances, you need to use the individual data to calculate standard deviations/variances.

But there is no way that they can be mathematically equivalent. In the $\sigma_{diff}$ case, they say take e.g. 30 people, do a test-retest, and look at the std of the difference between the two results. Then dividd it by sqrt(2). That is your error in predicting true score from observed score in future  single subject measurements. In the $\sigma_x$ case, they are saying ok you already did a test-retest study and calculated a reliability. Now you test 30 people and want to know the error. Take the std of their observed single measurement score and multiply by sqrt(1-R). They can’t be the same
